# Как узнать, с какими флагами компилировалась утилита sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

Как узнать, какие
[настройки времени компиляции](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html)
использовались при компиляции конкретного экземпляра
утилиты `sqlite3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать команду
[`PRAGMA compile_options`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_compile_options):

> **PRAGMA compile_options;**
>
> This pragma returns the names of compile-time options used when building
> SQLite, one option per row.  The "SQLITE_" prefix is omitted from the returned
> option names.  […]

Пример вывода на ОС *Ubuntu 20.04*:

```
$ echo 'PRAGMA compile_options;' | sqlite3
COMPILER=gcc-9.3.0
ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB
ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
ENABLE_FTS3_TOKENIZER
ENABLE_FTS4
ENABLE_FTS5
ENABLE_JSON1
ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION
ENABLE_PREUPDATE_HOOK
ENABLE_RTREE
ENABLE_SESSION
ENABLE_STMTVTAB
ENABLE_UNKNOWN_SQL_FUNCTION
ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY
ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT
HAVE_ISNAN
LIKE_DOESNT_MATCH_BLOBS
MAX_SCHEMA_RETRY=25
MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=250000
OMIT_LOOKASIDE
SECURE_DELETE
SOUNDEX
THREADSAFE=1
USE_URI
```